# DocuSign API update envelope notification settings

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using the PHP SDK. I created a user account under my admin account. I use "send on behalf of" to send envelopes from the user account. I am able to check the status of and download completed envelope documents and tab data with the master account, but I am unable to update the envelope notification settings from the master account.

The error I get is:

```
"errorCode": "USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS",
"message": "This user lacks sufficient permissions to access this resource."
```

Am I unable to update the notification settings on behalf of another user through the API? Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
$envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);

$expirations = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Expirations();
$expirations->setExpireAfter('120');
$expirations->setExpireEnabled('true');
$expirations->setExpireWarn('0');

$reminders = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Reminders();
$reminders->setReminderDelay('5');
$reminders->setReminderEnabled('true');
$reminders->setReminderFrequency('5');

$envelope_notification_request = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeNotificationRequest();

$envelope_notification_request->setReminders($reminders);
$envelope_notification_request->setExpirations($expirations);
$envelope_notification_request->setUseAccountDefaults('true');

$envelopeApi->updateNotificationSettings($accountId, $id, 
$envelope_notification_request);
```

This is when I get an error. I have tried using SendOnBehalfOf in the headers and without, with no change in results. Does anyone know if it is simply not possible to update the notification settings on behalf of another user with the API?

Thank you

Comment: master account means Admin User in DS Account? are your trying to update notification of the envelopes which were sent by a User in your DS Account using Admin User's credentials?

Comment: Yes, I am using admin credentials with "sendonbehalfof" as a user in my DS account. I can do other operations like update envelope, but not update notification settings.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth JWT Grant is the recommended authentication technique instead of the old SOBO system. See https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-php-jwt for an example of how to do this.

That probably isn't the issue but can only help.

The best would be to set the notification parameters when you create the envelope.

Another possibility: when you try to set the notification parameters are you sure that the envelope is not complete?

Next idea: use the [API Logging system](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to see exactly what was sent to DocuSign. Check it against the [API reference page](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/updateNotificationSettings) for that call as a check that the call is being made correctly.

Finally, I don't understand why you're requesting the account defaults and also trying to set the notification parameters. Wouldn't it be one or the other?

Comment: Hello and thank you for the detail! First, I have made it so envelopes sent out in the future will have the correct notification settings, but I wanted to bulk-update existing envelopes with the API. Using site defaults and also specifying notification settings was simply a code-typo in my example. Normally I'd do one or the other, but I was unable to do either. I've decided to manually resend the existing envelopes on my own (using the API) since that is the easiest path. Is SOBO going to be deprecated? Is it easy to swap out SOBO with JWT grant in my existing application?

Comment: I'm glad you have a solution. Legacy Authentication / SOBO does not yet have a deprecation schedule. And existing implementations will continue to work since we don't want to cause breaking changes. Switching to JWT Grant at some point should be straight forward the next time you upgrade your application. See the [eg-01-*](https://github.com/docusign?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=eg-01&type=&language=) examples.

Comment: As an Admin you do no need to do SOBO to update notifications via API, instead with Admin credentials you can update notifications for any envelope in your account via API only.